# ASUS rog b450-f faulty ram slot - game crashing

Tags: memory, asus

So Basically I just bought:
Ryzen 7 2700x
Asus rog b450-f gaming 2
Dddr4-3200 corsair vengeance 2x8gb

The issue is:

- If i put the two ram stick in the A2 & B2 slot, then all games start to randomly crash as soon I start play (note the game crashes not the windows, i can still close the game and continune using windows)
- If i put the two ram stick in A1 & B1 all works fine (but i can't use the full 3200mhz speed)

I am the only one with this issue? Is the mobo faulty ?

I have run memtest for over an hour without any errors

### Edit 1:

Nevermind: the game crashed again even when using A1 & B1 slots. Don't know what to do now

Comment: Run a memtest86 pass and see what it reports. Swap the modules, run memtest86 again. If errors are at the same addresses then it's a faulty slot.

Comment: I have run memtest for over an hour and no errors were reported

Comment: The memory and slots seem fine then. Is the BIOS up to date? Are your memory modules on motherboard's compatibility list?

Comment: the BIOS is up to date, there is a newer version but it's still in beta so i won't updgrade to it yet. Regarding the compatibility I think so: Corsair Vengeance LPX should be fully compatible with asus rog strix. The strange think is that when i use A2&B2 the games crash, but the windows (or other benchmarks) never crashes... that's so strange

Comment: @gronostaj: nevermind, the game crashed again even with A1 & B1, don't know what other test I can do...

Comment: That sounds more and more like a problem with the game rather than hardware.

Comment: it happens with both Valhalla and Horizon zero dawn

Comment: @gronostaj: I replaced my ram with Crucial Ballistix and now it seems it's working without crash !

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the Corsair RAM with a Crucial Ballistix and the games are not crashing anymore.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1022545)

Comment: Hi Dave, i am the original author. That's why i answered this

Comment: You should merge your accounts as you seem yo have two. https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts